# Ember js : load multiple template on one page with data

Tags: ember.js

I am working on a application in ember.js . I have an few questions to all of you guys. First lets discuss about my application points and then what problem I am facing in.

1. Application is about something like a drawing a plans like a "auto cad ". For this purpose I am using d3.js library
2. For a drawing purpose we have different sections like Fire, Water, etc..Satelite All of this sections have different svg container for drawing.
3. After this things I have one module for email this sections to a particular email id in three ways

   3.1 Current Section wise email (Means if we drawing in a fire section then If we send email then svg of fire section will send as a form of pdf) (Done)

   3.2 At a time all the sections svg content in PDF. (Here my actual problem starts)

In this point all sections email I am getting problem in retrieve all section svg's at a time. Because the current section is already loaded in a view, template with data , But how can I get all the sections template with its drawing data (svg element's).

I created my route like this

```
emailPDF = Ember.Route.extend({

    setupController: function(controller, model)
    {
        alert("Controller setup");
        this.controllerFor('fire').set('model', model);
        this.controllerFor('gas').set('model', model);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this._super();
        this.render('fire', {           // the template to render
            into: 'emailPDF',       // the template to render into
            outlet: 'fire',              // the name of the outlet in that template
            controller: 'fire'        // the controller to use for the template
        });
        this.render('gas', {
            into: 'emailPDF',
            outlet: 'gas',
            controller: 'gas'
        });
    }
});
```

And the template is like :

```
<div id="fire_test">
    {{outlet 'fire'}}
</div>
<div id="gas_test">
    {{outlet 'gas'}}
</div>
```

Then I transition this route from one controller like this :

```
this.transitionToRoute('emailPDF');
```

But here in the allSections template I am getting previous template that I have already open in the place of fire and gas outlet not able to render fire and gas template.

Please tell me if i am doing something wrong...

Comment: I'm really confused about this question. Do you want to get all these small embedded apps and turn them into one proper app or you want to create another app to control your existing apps within this website?

Comment: Thanks for your time @MilkyWayJoe,  See for example lets say I have two links "Home" and "Contact us". Both having different views, controller, template. And in both pages data is coming from database. Separately it is working fine. But now I want to display both the pages in a single page no links and no clicks. In short I have to merge all of these things in a single page. Like this two pages I have 16 sections and I have to display all of those sections in a single page. Actually I am beginner in ember.js

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe  Do you need some code snippet about this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want to do here is something like this... You need to create a route, say HomeAndContact.  In this route create a template.  You have 2 options here, make the template something like:

```
{{outlet 'home'}}
{{outlet 'contact'}}
```

Or you could also just do:

```
{{render 'home'}}
{{render 'contact'}}
```

I would advise against the second option because it will be deprecated/is not aligned with what Ember is doing going forward.

To do the first option, you will need to have some code like this in your HomeAndContactRoute:

```
HomeAndContactRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('home').set('model', model);
    this.controllerFor('contact').set('model', model);
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('home', {           // the template to render
      into: 'homeAndContact',       // the template to render into
      outlet: 'home',              // the name of the outlet in that template
      controller: 'home'        // the controller to use for the template
    });
    this.render('contact', {
      into: 'homeAndContact',
      outlet: 'contact',
      controller: 'contact'
    });
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not working how? Also maybe you could provide some more of your code, or even better a jsbin

Comment: I apologize but jsbin is not possible for now due to more dependencies in code

Comment: Hi, let me describe the issue which I face to make sure we both are on same page. What I need is, I want to draw some shape (i.e. Rect, Circle) based on database values and execute Ember component which return HTML. This HTML is nothing but what we can see by doing view source. Here this Ember component execution process is runtime. For e.g. I have main template and in that I have loaded Home1 template. In Home1 template there is a button say Generate HTML.

Comment: Once user click on this button then I want to execute component let say Home1Component runtime and require result in HTML. Do not want to load this Home1Component in to Home1Template. Also the database data is in some list/array so I need to loop through this data and for each data want to execute component (i.e.Home1Component, Home2Component, Home3Component etc..) runtime and want to generate HTML.

Comment: I apologize but I'm really not understanding what you're trying to do here, you can render a component anywhere at anytime, and if you need it to be only after a certain event then you can set a flag that is used in an {{#if}} block.  I realize you probably can't put your code in a jsbin, but can you at least make something similar in a jsbin? Or post some of your code and the errors you are getting? Without any of this it will be very difficult to help you

Comment: Sure @bmeyers Give me some time I will make some scenario for you in a jsbin. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78424/discussion-between-rahul-dabhi-and-bmeyers).

Comment: Hi @bmeyers  can you please check this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334382/emberjs-can-i-set-controller-in-view-inside-didinsertelement

Comment: Hi @bmeyers, I have a question. If we have to start one process in a parent window and can we executes in a pop up window with current state of parent window ?.  Can we do like this ?