# Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined TypeError:

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Here this is my route. When I am calling this route using `trasitionToRoute` method from another controller I am getting an error.

**Here is my router :**

```
 App.AllSectionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

     renderTemplate: function() {
        //this._super(); 

        this.render('fire', { outlet: 'fire', into: 'allSections' });

        this.render('gas', { outlet: 'gas', into: 'allSections' });

    }
});
```

**Here is my template :**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="allSections">
        <hr/>
        <hr/>
        <div class='outletArea'>
            {{outlet "fire"}}
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class='outletArea'>
            {{outlet "gas"}}
        </div>
    </script>
```

If I don't call `this._super(controller, model);` statement, at that time I am getting error of `connectOutlet of undefined`.

But when I call this statement, then the error will not come out, but the extra templates that I have to render like "fire" and "gas" into the template "allsections" are not rendered. It is rendered the current template into "allSections", but that is the template that was already open.

Please suggest me if I am going wrong.....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what else you're doing, but I can't reproduce your issue. 
I've created this [**jsbin**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tofikonapu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) to simulate your scenario and it works fine. I'm calling `this._super()` tho:

```
App.AllSectionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
     this._super();

     this.render('fire', {
       into: 'allSections',
       outlet: 'fire'
     });

     this.render('gas', {
       into: 'allSections',
       outlet: 'gas'
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: You are right but when I call this._super() method then in allSections template render that template that is currently open not 'gas' and 'fire'. Thanks for edit my grammer and sorry for my bad english. Why it is render previous template instead of gas and fire. Thats my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "previous template"?

Comment: Hi @MilkyWayJoe For example , If i have already open gas template and then I perform this task means open "gas" and "fire" in "allSections" at that time only the "gas" template will render in "allSections" in both outlets in allSections

Comment: I think this error causing problem with render new templates please check it      EmberError {description: undefined, fileName: undefined, lineNumber: undefined, message: "Assertion Failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: ID__Plans_undefined81636ff3-f0e4-4556-8cb7-a8f5956801d3", name: "Error"…}

Comment: There's clearly a piece missing. Do you think you can edit that jsbin so it shows your scenario? I've tried to reproduce it but I could get it to error out with what you described so far

Comment: See my old question that I am going to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053762/ember-js-load-multiple-template-on-one-page-with-data

Comment: Hi, let me describe the issue which I face to make sure we both are on same page. What I need is, I want to draw some shape (i.e. Rect, Circle) based on database values and execute Ember component which return HTML.  This HTML is nothing but what we can see by doing view source. Here this Ember component execution process is runtime.
For e.g. I have main template and in that I have loaded Home1 template. In Home1 template there is  a  button say Generate HTML.

Comment: Once user click on this button then I want to execute component let say Home1Component runtime and require result in HTML. Do not want to load this Home1Component in to Home1Template.  Also the database data is in some list/array so I need to loop through this data and for each data want to execute component (i.e.Home1Component, Home2Component, Home3Component etc..) runtime and want to generate HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77886/discussion-between-rahul-dabhi-and-milkywayjoe).