# Emberjs - Can I set controller in View inside didInsertElement?

Tags: ember.js

I am new to EmberJS and have existing code. 
I have a login form which should be posted on hitting enter button.

First time everything goes smooth and working as expected, once I log out-  it clears the session and redirects me to login view and then the problem starts as `that.get("controller")` is undefined this time.

My Login view is having below code

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    var that = this;
    Ember.$(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            that.get("controller").send("login");
            // **As that.get("controller") is undefined I want to set that**
            //that.set("controller"); //- **CAN I DO THIS?**            
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is - `that.get("controller")` is `undefined`.

When I tried `that.set("controller");` - it says that

> Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object

Comment: Please provide more code, the entire view for starters, as well as the handlebars file

Comment: No views in latest emberjs. Better to upgrade to latest one. If you want to access controller in components, pass as an extra parameter. For eg:- In route templates {{companentName controllerInstance=this}}